# Nodejs Service crashed and exit after few hours

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection, mysql-connector, nodejs-server

After start node service with "node start" it works fine full day.
Then when I check next day morning I found it crashed or packet out of order and exit from node service.

If I Just start the service and do not load my application then no query run in background and next morning I found that service is not crashed and running.

So I quiet realize that If any MySql query run by application then It crashed after few hours.

*So is there any problem of connection issue?
Do I need to close after each query execution?*

**My Connection Sample:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const sequelize =
  new Sequelize(process.env.DBNAME, process.env.DBUSER, process.env.DBPASS,
    {
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.HOST_PORT,
      dialect: 'mysql',
      operatorsAliases: 0,
      timezone: "+06:00",

      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
      }
    }
  )

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**My Query sample:**

```
const dbConnect = require('../database/db');

let getEmployeeData = 
      await dbConnect.query(
                  `Select * From employee`, 
                  {type: QueryTypes.SELECT});

return res.json({data: getEmployeeData});
```

Comment: Usually these type of symptoms indicate that you're leaking some type of resource such as memory, file handles, database connections, etc... and when you run out, the process either stops working or crashes.

Comment: @jfriend00 ,  I am getting 2 errors code:
1. code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2. code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER'

Comment: Both `PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER` and `PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST` can be produced when you run out of database connections.  I would guess you are leaking database connections and the system runs out.

Comment: @jfriend00, can you please tell me how to end the connection after using "dbConnect.query" in my upper code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your particular database.  Hopefully someone else can help with that.